# actionButton triggers after reconnect

Tags: r, shiny

I have a Shiny app running on my local network where a button opens a modal.
Now I have two scenarios:

Open the Shiny app in the browser and shut down the Shiny app. Restart the Shiny app
-> The browser will reconnect, and the actionButton is not triggered.
**Works as expected.**

Open the Shiny app in the browser and press the actionButton. The modal will pop up, and I close it. Then shut down the Shiny app. Restart the Shiny app
-> The browser will reconnect, and the actionButton will be triggered, and the modal will show up.
**What triggers the actionButton?**

How can I prevent the actionButton from being triggered by a reconnection?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
 actionButton("goModal","Go!") 
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  
  session$allowReconnect("force")
  
  observeEvent(input$goModal,{
    myModal = modalDialog(
                h3("goModal"),
                title = "Why triggers after reconnect", easyClose = TRUE, footer = modalButton("Ok")
              )
    showModal(myModal)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the observer beeing triggered on reconnect by setting `ignoreInit = TRUE`.

The issue is, that your `input$goModal` is no longer `NULL` after it was pressed once in the current session. However, after reconnecting to the session the observer is again initialized and therefore executes. When starting a new session, the default setting `ignoreNULL = TRUE` prevents the observer from running.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("goModal","Go!") 
)

server <- function(input, output,session) {
  session$allowReconnect("force")
  observeEvent(input$goModal,{
    myModal = modalDialog(
      h3("goModal"),
      title = "Why triggers after reconnect", easyClose = TRUE, footer = modalButton("Ok")
    )
    showModal(myModal)
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```